# Implement big int in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, int

How to implement big int in matlab if possible?

```
base = 115740200527109164239523414760926155534485715860090261532154107313946218459149402375178179458041461723723231563839316251515439564315555249353831328479173170684416728715378198172203100328308536292821245983596065287318698169565702979765910089654821728828592422299160041156491980943427556153020487552135890973413

exp = 16205962307261760189575459786273943315321167650525279039226402620183364231925409315656258599329538647429058153827986967502066336581939528313657921572960065150727259976179025776971363924442875150959953467637629858540057691397256164559842414074042495886675668598268975047781126857869572720344318367729860654075

mod = 124325339146889384540494091085456630009856882741872806181731279018491820800119460022367403769795008250021191767583423221479185609066059226301250167164084041279837566626881119772675984258163062926954046545485368458404445166682380071370274810671501916789361956272226105723317679562001235501455748016154805420913
```

This what i need to calculate `modexp(base,exp,mod)`

Comment: Extremely ununderstandable

Comment: "How to implement big int in matlab if not possible?" - seriously? Or are you just trolling? If so, get out now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IT ALREADY IS IMPLEMENTED, since you can use [vpi](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic), as found on the file exchange.

```
base = vpi('115740200527109164239523414760926155534485715860090261532154107313946218459149402375178179458041461723723231563839316251515439564315555249353831328479173170684416728715378198172203100328308536292821245983596065287318698169565702979765910089654821728828592422299160041156491980943427556153020487552135890973413');

expon = vpi('16205962307261760189575459786273943315321167650525279039226402620183364231925409315656258599329538647429058153827986967502066336581939528313657921572960065150727259976179025776971363924442875150959953467637629858540057691397256164559842414074042495886675668598268975047781126857869572720344318367729860654075');

modulus = vpi('124325339146889384540494091085456630009856882741872806181731279018491820800119460022367403769795008250021191767583423221479185609066059226301250167164084041279837566626881119772675984258163062926954046545485368458404445166682380071370274810671501916789361956272226105723317679562001235501455748016154805420913');

powermod(base,expon,modulus)
ans =
96688554274778609934477562662404606264395384510288145077254270650448790387722984014247388006652841434990300433933136603474993407330696644666217689882824803664362981750613122185159564556754728021340332299439811221240883496369370843657919287413245488923703097829207075814277190552896301852217610348268590146354
```

Or, you can write it yourself. It was not that difficult, just time consuming.

By the way, it is a TERRIBLE idea to use variable names like exp and mod. Learn not to overload valuable functions in MATLAB with variables of the same name.

Comment: Are you the author of `vpi` function, if so I just saw it. Amazing function. I could only do +1 (wanted to do more :))

Comment: Yes, vpi is mine. thanx.

Answer (score 3):

The go-to place for extra functionality is usually the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

For example, you can use the BigInteger java class within Matlab as follows:

```
baseValue = java.math.BigInteger('115740200527109164239523414760926155534485715860090261532154107313946218459149402375178179458041461723723231563839316251515439564315555249353831328479173170684416728715378198172203100328308536292821245983596065287318698169565702979765910089654821728828592422299160041156491980943427556153020487552135890973413')
expValue  = java.math.BigInteger('16205962307261760189575459786273943315321167650525279039226402620183364231925409315656258599329538647429058153827986967502066336581939528313657921572960065150727259976179025776971363924442875150959953467637629858540057691397256164559842414074042495886675668598268975047781126857869572720344318367729860654075')
modValue  = java.math.BigInteger('124325339146889384540494091085456630009856882741872806181731279018491820800119460022367403769795008250021191767583423221479185609066059226301250167164084041279837566626881119772675984258163062926954046545485368458404445166682380071370274810671501916789361956272226105723317679562001235501455748016154805420913')

result    = baseValue.modPow(expValue, modValue)
```

Returns:

```
result =
96688554274778609934477562662404606264395384510288145077254270650448790387722984014247388006652841434990300433933136603474993407330696644666217689882824803664362981750613122185159564556754728021340332299439811221240883496369370843657919287413245488923703097829207075814277190552896301852217610348268590146354
```